# Calculating PI with Fortran & CUDA

Tags: cuda, fortran, pgi

I am trying to make a simple program in PGI's fortran compiler. This simple program will use the graphics card to calculate pi using the "dart board" algorithm. After battling with this program for quite some time now I have finally got it to behave for the most part. However, I am currently stuck on passing back the results properly. I must say, this is a rather tricky program to debug since I can no longer shove any print statements into the subroutine. This program currently returns all zeros. I am not really sure what is going on, but I have two ideas. Both of which I am not sure how to fix:

1. The CUDA kernel is not running somehow?
2. I am not converting the values properly? `pi_parts = pi_parts_d`

Well, this is the status of my current program. All variables with `_d` on the end stand for the CUDA prepared device memory where all the other variables (with the exception of the CUDA kernel) are typical Fortran CPU prepared variables. Now there are some print statements I have commented out that I have already tried out from CPU Fortran land. These commands were to check if I really was generating the random numbers properly. As for the CUDA method, I have currently commented out the calculations and replaced `z` to statically equal to `1` just to see something happen.

```
module calcPi
contains
    attributes(global) subroutine pi_darts(x, y, results, N)
        use cudafor
        implicit none
        integer :: id
        integer, value :: N
        real, dimension(N) :: x, y, results
        real :: z

        id = (blockIdx%x-1)*blockDim%x + threadIdx%x

        if (id .lt. N) then
            ! SQRT NOT NEEDED, SQRT(1) === 1
            ! Anything above and below 1 would stay the same even with the applied
            ! sqrt function. Therefore using the sqrt function wastes GPU time.
            z = 1.0
            !z = x(id)*x(id)+y(id)*y(id)
            !if (z .lt. 1.0) then
            !   z = 1.0
            !else
            !   z = 0.0
            !endif
            results(id) = z
        endif
    end subroutine pi_darts
end module calcPi

program final_project
    use calcPi
    use cudafor
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: N = 400
    integer :: i
    real, dimension(N) :: x, y, pi_parts
    real, dimension(N), device :: x_d, y_d, pi_parts_d
    type(dim3) :: grid, tBlock

    ! Initialize the random number generaters seed
    call random_seed()

    ! Make sure we initialize the parts with 0
    pi_parts = 0

    ! Prepare the random numbers (These cannot be generated from inside the
    ! cuda kernel)
    call random_number(x)
    call random_number(y)

    !write(*,*) x, y

    ! Convert the random numbers into graphics card memory land!
    x_d = x
    y_d = y
    pi_parts_d = pi_parts

    ! For the cuda kernel
    tBlock = dim3(256,1,1)
    grid = dim3((N/tBlock%x)+1,1,1)

    ! Start the cuda kernel
    call pi_darts<<<grid, tblock>>>(x_d, y_d, pi_parts_d, N)

    ! Transform the results into CPU Memory
    pi_parts = pi_parts_d
    write(*,*) pi_parts

    write(*,*) 'PI: ', 4.0*sum(pi_parts)/N
end program final_project
```

**EDIT TO CODE:**
Changed various lines to reflect the fixes mentioned by: `Robert Crovella`. Current status:  error caught by `cuda-memcheck` revealing: `Program hit error 8 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch` on my machine.

If there is any method I can use to test this program please let me know. I am throwing darts and seeing where they land for my current style of debugging with CUDA. Not the most ideal, but it will have to do until I find another way.

May the Fortran Gods have mercy on my soul at this dark hour.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out this worked Fortran example for the Monte Carlo computation of π with the help of the GPU: https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v2n1a4.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile and run your program I get a segfault.  This is due to the last parameter you are passing to the kernel (`N_d`):

```
call pi_darts<<<grid, tblock>>>(x_d, y_d, pi_parts_d, N_d)
```

Since `N` is a scalar quantity, the kernel is expecting to use it directly, rather than as a pointer.  So when you pass a pointer to device data (`N_d`), the process of setting up the kernel generates a seg fault (in host code!) as it attempts to access the value `N`, which should be passed directly as:

```
call pi_darts<<<grid, tblock>>>(x_d, y_d, pi_parts_d, N)
```

When I make that change to the code you have posted, I then get actual printed output (instead of a seg fault), which is an array of ones and zeroes (256 ones, followed by 144 zeroes, for a total of `N`=400 values), followed by the calculated PI value (which happens to be 2.56 in this case (4*256/400), since you have made the kernel basically a dummy kernel).

This line of code is also probably not doing what you want:

```
grid = dim3(N/tBlock%x,1,1)
```

With `N` = 400 and `tBlock%x` = 256 (from previous code lines), the result of the calculation is 1 (ie. `grid` ends up at `(1,1,1)` which amounts to one threadblock).  But you really want to launch 2 threadblocks, so as to cover the entire range of your data set (`N` = 400 elements).  There's a number of ways to fix this, but for simplicity let's just always add 1 to the calculation:

```
grid = dim3((N/tBlock%x)+1,1,1)
```

Under these circumstances, when we launch grids that are larger (in terms of total threads) than our data set size (512 threads but only 400 data elements in this example) it's customary to put a *thread check* near the beginning of our kernel (in this case, after the initialization of `id`), to prevent out-of-bounds accesses, like so:

```
if (id .lt. N) then
```

(and a corresponding `endif` at the very end of the kernel code)  This way, only the threads that correspond to actual valid data are allowed to do any work.

With the above changes, your code should be essentially functional, and you should be able to revert your kernel code to the proper statements and start to get an estimate of PI.

Note that you can check the CUDA API for error return codes, and you can also run your code with `cuda-memcheck` to get an idea of whether the kernel is making out-of-bounds accesses.  Niether of these would have helped with this particular seg fault, however.

Comment: Thank you so very much for responding to my question with such a thoughtful answer explaining each individual problem. I am not getting a sigabrt anymore, however I am getting all 0's. I ran the `cuda-memcheck` on the program and it currently gives me: `Program hit error 8 on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch`. I have not been able to track down what or where that comes from. Could it be an allocation problem? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Error 8 is "Invalid Device Function".  The description is: "The requested device function does not exist or is not compiled for the proper device architecture."  Probably you are not compiling for the proper device architecture.  If you still need help, indicate what GPU you have and what your compile command line is.

Comment: I have been using `pgf95 -o program.exe main.cuf` to compile my application. My graphics card is a nVidia GeForce 9800GTX+. I did not see any examples on how to specify the system architecture. I always thought the compiler would choose the currently running architecture. I guess it doesn't? Thank you again for this great help.

Comment: I suggest you read chapter 7 of the [pgi compiler user's guide](https://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf).  Your 9800GTX is a [cc1.1 device](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).  Try adding the `-ta=nvidia,cc11` flag to your compile command line.  You can get some command line help also with `pgf95 -help`.  I'm not sure, but I think it's possible that if you don't specify an architecture, the default may be cc2.0 which wouldn't run on your device.

Comment: YES, there we go! The device architecture needed to be set to an older style device! Thank you soooo much!