# Mixed language CUDA programming

Tags: c, cuda, fortran

What is the way to incorporate CUDA code with Fortran and C code (Mixed language programming). The Fortran code calls a C function which in turn  calls the CUDA kernel. For example.

Fortran function:

```
if(flag.eq.1) call c_func
```

C function:

```
void c_func()
{
  /* copy data to device 
  ....
  cuda_kernel<<< kernel parameters>>>();

  /* copy data from device to Host
  ........
}
```

What is the way to compile this type of code?

Comment: You want just to call a C function (which calls some CUDA, but you do not interact with CUDA from Fortran directly?) There are TONS of questions about that. Just search C and Fortran in the top right search line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran+c Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Or if you need something more involved, you should provide more information what exactly that should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there are many possible approaches to this.  But following the example you've given, it should be fairly straightforward.

The task can be separated into two pieces:

1. How to call a C function from Fortran
2. How to call a CUDA function from C

I think your question probably revolves around the first piece, and as such it is not really CUDA-specific.  For the second piece of course there are many examples here on the cuda tag, as well as [cuda sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#abstract) and a [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#abstract).

One method that may help to streamline the first piece is to use the `ISO_C_BINDING` [builtin module](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) which is built into many current fortran distributions.  This module defines a number of types which are useful for passing data between C and Fortran.

You can then create an `INTERFACE` block to define the parameters of your C function that you wish to call from fortran.  Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat cuda_test.f90
!=======================================================================================================================
!Interface to cuda C functions
!=======================================================================================================================
module cuda_test

  use iso_c_binding

  interface
     !
     integer(c_int) function cudatestfunc(idata, isize) bind(C, name="cudatestfunc")
       use iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       type(c_ptr),value :: idata
       integer(c_int),value :: isize
     end function cudatestfunc
     !
  end interface

end module cuda_test



!=======================================================================================================================
program main
!=======================================================================================================================

  use iso_c_binding

  use cuda_test

  type(c_ptr) :: mydata
  integer*4, target   :: mysize,myresult
  integer*4,dimension(:),allocatable,target :: darray
  mysize = 100
  allocate(darray(mysize))
  darray = (/ (1, I = 1, mysize) /)
  mydata = c_loc(darray)
  myresult = cudatestfunc(mydata, mysize)

  write (*, '(A, I10)') "  result: ", myresult
  write (*,*)

end program main
$ cat cuda_test.cu
#include <stdio.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void testkernel(int *data, int size){

  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) data[0] += data[i];
}
extern "C" {
int cudatestfunc(int *data, int size){

  int *d_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, size*sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  testkernel<<<1,1>>>(d_data, size);
  int result;
  cudaMemcpy(&result, d_data, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaCheckErrors("cuda error");
  return result;
}
}
$ gfortran -c cuda_test.f90 -o cuda_testf.o                 
$ nvcc -c cuda_test.cu -o cuda_testc.o                      
$ gfortran cuda_testc.o cuda_testf.o -o cuda_test -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lstdc++
$ ./cuda_test
  result:        100

$
```

(tested on RHEL 6.2, GNU 4.4.7, CUDA 7.0)

Notes/Other options:

1. If you only need to call CUDA runtime API functions, you can call those directly from fortran without needing any C/C++ files (if you create your own bindings).  Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507169/find-available-graphics-card-memory-using-fortran/27576218#27576218).
2. If you only need to call CUSPARSE or CUBLAS library functions, there are some bindings created for you, that are included with the CUDA distribution.  Those bindings by default on linux are installed at `/usr/local/cuda/src`.  A worked example for the cublas bindings is contained in [the cublas documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#appendix-b-cublas-fortran-bindings).
3. If you need to call other CUDA library functions directly from fortran, it's not terribly difficult to create your own bindings.  A worked example is [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/882492/gpu-accelerated-libraries/using-cusolverdn-in-fortran-code/) for a simple set of operations in CUSOLVER.
4. You can also write [CUDA Fortran](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-fortran) code directly. ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330979/calculating-pi-with-fortran-cuda) is an example.)  This requires the [CUDA Fortran compiler from PGI](https://www.pgroup.com/resources/cudafortran.htm).
5. You can also write OpenACC Fortran code.  This requires one of the available OpenACC compilers, such as that from PGI.  A PGI free-for-academic use or trial version is available [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc)